# Преобразование String^ в string

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

Есть `textBox`, его содержимое должно стать названием нового текстового файла(txt/csv/json). Проблема в том, `textBox` может принимать значение `String^`, а запись в название файла возможна с типом `string` или `char` (если я правильно понял). Ошибка:

> E0415 не существует подходящего конструктора для преобразования из "System::String ^" в "std::basic_ofstream<char, std::char_traits>"

```
String^ n= textBox1->Text+".csv";
ofstream fname=(n);
```

Как преобразовать из `String^` в `string` или сделать так, чтобы это работало, может без преобразования, а как-то по-другому.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если уже используете cli (.NET), то лучше сразу и местные классы использовать. Вот ссылка на [msdn](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/file-handling-and-i-o-cpp-cli?view=msvc-160) где есть просто куча примеров.

Так как у Вас ostream, то наверное хочется писать в файл.

```
// text_write.cpp
// compile with: /clr
using namespace System;
using namespace System::IO;

int main()
{
   String^ fileName = "textfile.txt";

   StreamWriter^ sw = gcnew StreamWriter(fileName);
   sw->WriteLine("A text file is born!");
   sw->Write("You can use WriteLine");
   sw->WriteLine("...or just Write");
   sw->WriteLine("and do {0} output too.", "formatted");
   sw->WriteLine("You can also send non-text objects:");
   sw->WriteLine(DateTime::Now);
   sw->Close();
   Console::WriteLine("a new file ('{0}') has been written", fileName);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло, я хотел бы еще спросить, как сделать проверку, если 2 окна формы закрыты то полностью остановить приложение(у меня всего 3 окна, сначала открывается главное окно потом по нажатию на кнопку открываются еще 2 окна, и если их оба закрыть то программа не останавливается) и я не знаю как сделать эту проверку, если закрыть оба окна то приложение должно остановиться полностью(Application::Exit)

Comment: это как бы совсем другой вопрос:). но никто не мешает при закрытии формы проверять, а закрыта ли вторая. и принимать решение. А можно посмотреть на https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/get-list-of-all-open-forms-in-windows-application1 и проверять кол-во открытых форм.